# Why does the new update for my app remove it from the launcher?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I placed a shortcut to my app on the main Android screen, the one you see after unlocking the phone. I then installed my latest update over the top. The app then disappeared from the launcher (but was still in the main list of apps).

I have released many updates where this hasn't happened. However it has happened before, when I replaced our main activity with a new class. That was understandable as maybe the launcher was holding a reference to the class name (rather than the application identifier?).

However this time, that hasn't happened. I *have* changed the base activity code, and added some new classes to its jar (that then links, and always has linked, with the main eclipse project, rather than be part of it). I've also added some stuff to our manifest:

- `support-screens` now contains `android:resizable="true"`
- have upped the `minSdkVersion` from 8 to 10
- have added a bunch of permissions, including `CD2_MESSAGE` and `WAKE_LOCK`
- have added a new activity, reciever and service

Any ideas?

Comment: I have recently experienced this when I changed the launcher activity in the manifest (actually just the package name of the launcher activity). Maybe you did something similar?

Comment: Does this app installs on the external SD Card? So do you have `android:installLocation="auto"` or `preferExternal` declared in your manifest? Sometimes it happened for me too, on a few custom ROMs, tho I never managed to find the reason.

Comment: @Nachi like I said, the main launcher activity name hasn't changed this time. When this happened before, that was the issue.

Comment: @hundeva yeah it's `preferExternal`, but it's always been like that. That's not a new change.